# stream.distinct() returning non-distinct elements

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm having trouble getting my code to properly return a list of distinct elements. I have a list of objects `listToObserve` that contain my `GroupModel` which has a `SimpleStringProperty` which I use the `equals` method to determine equality.

```
class GroupModel(name: String = "myGroup") {
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(this, "groupName", name)
    var name: String by nameProperty

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
        other as GroupModel
        if (nameProperty.value != other.nameProperty.value) return false
        return true
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
val distinctGroups = listToObserve.map { it.group }.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()).toObservable()
```

My understanding from this is distinct should compare each group by the name and if it is equal then it won't add it, but it is adding groups with the exact same name. Can someone help me spot my mistake?

Comment: Does SimpleStringProperty implements equals? Also you need to implement hashCode, the rule is that if you override equals you should override hashCode as well.

Comment: I have I simply cut it out for the example. I actually just verified the equals() is working as it should by manually checking two groups with the same name. So I think the problem is how I'm creating distinctGroups

Comment: you also should override hashcode

Comment: Please show the SimpleStringProperty class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it is the javafx13 default implementation found here https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html